# Is there any tool to analyze a web page with css box model?

Tags: html, css

Web page is getting fancier each day, while the basis of structure is all the same.
That is css box model.
So I wonder if there is any kind of tool to analyze a page with css box. That is:
1. input a page (url);
2. output the box structure of the page (png);

For example, the output could be something like:
[image]

With this, we can do a better review or rework on this web page. Right?
I will appreciate it if you could tell me something you know about this.

Comment: Inspect element? `* { outline: 1px solid black }`? What do you want?

Comment: @bjb568 Thanks, but with this I can only see the outline while no cascade structure of the componets. Right? Please see the demo picture presented in the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure inspect element will do it for you. What browser do you use?

Comment: @bjb568 maybe I didn't get your suggestion very well. I use chrome/firefox/IE10. Sorry but where should I apply the `*{outline: 1px solid black}`

Comment: Using outline won't work very well. Just right click and open the Dev Console/View Source/Inspect Element window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox browser provides a 3D tool for detailed checking of web page. It is a very interesting tool. You can check it like this.

Open the web-page in firefox and right click anywhere on the page. Select the `inspect element(Q)` from the menu. It will bring a new window at the bottom of page similar to firebug window. You can find the 3d view button on the right side. Click it and drag your webpage, then it will rotate as you like.

Here is the sample screenshot for apple.com website

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TuG6.jpg

Comment: Thanks, Nikhil. I just tried this and it worked well. I'm not used to 3D model though, the cross-sections is exactly what I want.

Comment: Here are two links if you are not able to find **3d view** just like me.
1.
[bring 3d button](http://superuser.com/questions/774846/does-firefox-30-still-have-the-3d-dom-viewer)
2.
[more troubleshooting options](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions]/923037)